# Embedding a youtube/sharepoint video to power bi

Tags: javascript, html, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am using HTML viewer visual in power bi to embed a youtube video into a power bi report but it is not working. The same code is working fine as an html page but inside the power bi dashboard its showing blank.
the following is the error when i published the dashboard on pBi service.
[Error img here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DosQy.png)

Open to suggestions and other ideas to implement the same.
P.s i m not interested in using button as hyperlinks to the video.

Ideas and suggestions to implement the same or a solution to the current problem.

Comment: Which visual (exact name/link) are you using? Are you using the embed URL of the video (https://www.youtube.com/embed/....)? Perhaps also try [HTML Content](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA200001930?tab=Overview)

Comment: I m using HTML content visual. and yes the embed URL of that video is passed in html

Comment: Have a look at: https://blog.enterprisedna.co/play-add-videos-in-power-bi/.